# cURL login to insecure URL with self generated certs and on submit json post

Tags: php, json, ssl, curl

I am having a problem to successful login with curl on a local url with self-generated certifications that POST the login form data and a function handle the submit.

I grab the post data with HttpFox, url https://mysite.loc/login/check and data username=anmail%40mail.com&password=mypass

curl code i tried:

```
function login($url,$data){
$fp = fopen("cookie.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
$login = curl_init();
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40000);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
ob_start();
return curl_exec ($login);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($login);
unset($login);    
}    
 echo login("https://mysite.loc/login/check/", "username=anmail%40mail.com&password=mypass");
```

And then use this code to grab a url with same cookie file:

```
function grab_page($site){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
ob_start();
return curl_exec ($ch);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close ($ch);
}

echo grab_page("https://mysite.loc/workstations/");
```

Login form looks like this:

```
<form class="m-t" role="form" id="login_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" autocomplete="off" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>
</form>
```

And the function that handles the submit:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login/check/",
        data: $('form#login_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.hasOwnProperty('message'))
            {
                swal('blabla', response.message, 'error')
            }
            if (response.hasOwnProperty('redirect'))
            {
                window.location.replace(response.redirect);
            }
            if (response.hasOwnProperty('ask_create_session'))
```

Can anyone suggest a possible solution ? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Do you get an error message? does it complain about your SSL certificate? Or are you getting "invalid username/password" or "session timeout" or ??

Comment: Login page is loading so i pass the SSL certificates i guess, but i cant login the login/check page doesn't return anything and using that cookie cant get https://mysite.loc/workstations/ page after :(

Comment: Given it's local can you add some logging to the server side? Log out what happens in the code at `/login/check/` and run the form. Then run your login code and see if you get the same stuff?  That'll narrow it down to whether the problem is in the login call, or the re-use of the cookies for the next.

Comment: The site is hosted on a device i can't access to do server side logging, i noticed that cookie.txt is empty what this means? i guess even on unsuccessful run on login/check/ url it's should have some content?

Comment: If I were writing a login page, I'd clear those cookies on an unsuccessful attempt.  The ajax looks for a property `message` and displays it as an error - do you get anything back that might be a message?

Comment: cookies looks like work fine since i tested with other side they just stored on my test server apache/ instead of www folder, the check/ return nothing on echo or page source.

Comment: i enable the headers curl_setopt($login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
and get that as a return
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 29 Apr 2017 00:49:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: ci_session=bla bla
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Comment: I found the solution!
Needed to edit the header like i capture them 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Connection: keep-alive',
    'Origin: https://frappe.loc',
    'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'

And it worked flawless :)